# Is it safe to use arbitrary values as the `ExclusiveStartKey` for a dynamodb scan or query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

From the DynamoDB API Reference for `ExclusiveStartKey` (for both `Scan` and `Query`), we have:

> The primary key of the first item that this operation will evaluate. Use the value that was returned for LastEvaluatedKey in the previous operation.

I have a use case in which I'd like to use `ExclusiveStartKey` to start a Scan from a specific known position (as opposed to using it to continue an existing scan). The first sentence above sounds like this is exactly okay, but the second sentence doesn't. That second sentence gives me pause particularly because it's not a "you should [...]" or "you must [...]", just a plain old imperative with no context or interpretation.

I can't find any examples on SO or elsewhere of people using `ExclusiveStartKey` in this way. It seems to work, but the API reference seems vague on whether this is going off-contract. Should I seek a different route? Has anyone used this in practice and can confirm that it's reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should use ExclusiveStartKey for this use case, as that is what it was made for. If you have a case where you do your first call and don't yet know where to begin (no LastEvaluatedKey) then you can simply not include ExclusiveStartKey as it is optional.

I think the second sentence is pretty clearly implying "should", and the reason they didn't say "must" is because you can technically use any scanned key, but you can, and in the case of properly scanning all objects, *should* use the LastEvaluatedKey.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB sort all your primary keys using a hash function and then store it on the right buckets. When scanning documents, the `ExclusiveStartKey` is used to know in which bucket we should continue the scan and also what's the next document on that bucket.

It completely safe to use any arbitrary key for `ExclusiveStartKey` as even DynamoDB can't predict on which bucket it will land. From the same reason it's also useless, unless you want to fetch random documents from the database.